# array giving random numbers at the end of array[7]

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

I am trying to correctly print the values inside the array. The program is supposed to take only numbers that are **13 digits or higher.** If I give **n** a number of 13 digits or 14 digits, the last position of the `long array[8]`, which is **array[7]**, gives random numbers such 4199280, or other 7 digit number. how can set **array[7] to 0** then, so it doesn't hinder in my multiplication later. Can someone help me fix what I might be doing wrong without knowing? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long countDigit(long long n);

int main(void)
{
    long n;

   //This is asking for the input
    do
    {
        n = get_long("Number: ");
    }
    while(!(countDigit(n)>12));

    //Checksum math
    long everyOther = 0;
    long array[8];
      int i = 0;


    while(n > 0)
    {

        long lastNumber = n/10;
        everyOther = lastNumber % 10;
        n = n / 100;
        printf("%li\n", everyOther);
        array[i] = everyOther;
        i++;

    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%li\n", array[0]);
    printf("%li\n", array[1]);
    printf("%li\n", array[2]);
    printf("%li\n", array[3]);
    printf("%li\n", array[4]);
    printf("%li\n", array[5]);
    printf("%li\n", array[6]);
    printf("%li\n", array[7]);

     printf("\n");


    // long Multi = ((2*(array[0])) + (2*(array[1])) + (2*(array[2])) + (2*(array[3]))
    //                 + (2*(array[4])) + (2*(array[5])) + (2*(array[6])) + (2*(array[7])));
    // printf("%li\n", Multi);
}


//This function helps us with the counting of the number
long countDigit(long long n) {
  return floor(log10(n) + 1);
}
```

Comment: You never set `array[7]` to anything

Comment: @M.M, I thought I declared the array by `long array[8]`, and the last position of that array is giving me the issue

Comment: Use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Will the loop assign to `array[7]`? My guess is that it doesn't.

Comment: @Chris Dodd, how can set array[7] to 0 then, so it doesn't hinder in my multiplication later.

Comment: `array[7] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

To see what is happening more clearly, try adding a printf to the loop just before or after setting array[i]:

```
printf("array[%d] = %li\n", i, everyOther);
```

this will show you exactly which elements of the array get set, and what they get set to.  You'll see, when the input is 13 or 14 digits, this will happen 7 times.  For example, if your input is 1234567890123, you'll see

```
array[0] = 2
array[1] = 0
array[2] = 8
array[3] = 6
array[4] = 4
array[5] = 2
array[6] = 0
```

thus showing that you're only setting those 7 values of the array.  So if you later try to print array[7], you'll get garbage; it has never been set to anything.